# SEO Positioning: Different URL for different kind of users in the same website

Tags: url, web, seo

I'm developing an eCommerce website, whose users can be of two kinds; ordinary people and business. The difference between them are short, business users has a special discount, so their prices are different; and a couple more of minor changes compared to ordinary people.

My question is if it matter if this two users has the same URL for the same modules, for example, if they are watching the catalog:

myapp.com/catalog

A business users could be:

myapp.com/business/catalog

I'm asking this question because of the SEO positioning; I need to know if this makes any difference longer than making the same URL for two kind of users.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to distinguish between ordinary people and business people (and show them different prices) they have to be logged in to your website. There is no need to make different URLs from the SEO point of view, because an indexing bot **cannot log in** and therefore cannot see the difference between two kind of users.

But this really depends on the approach you choose. You can make both of the pages with different prices visible to anynone and decide right after they log in if they can buy for the price. But I think it makes the shopping process too complicated from UX point of view. Imagine that ordinary user goes to business page, put goods with discount prices in to his shopping cart, logs in and then sees different prices because the system didn't recognize him as a business person. It can be very misleading for unexperienced user.